# Nginx unable to access parts of the website

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

Si I'm trying to run Invision Forums on nginx but it can't seem to access the uploads folder for some reason. It's most likely my configuration that's wrong but I'm not really sure since this is the first time I'm working with nginx.

[image]

Here's my configuration file:

```
worker_processes  1;
user www-data;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;


    server {

    listen        80;
    listen        [::]:80;
    server_name   localhost;
    root          /var/www/forums;
    index         index.php;

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
}

}
```

Comment: Your screenshot is cutting off the errors show, what do those errors exactly?

Comment: It's not cut off as far as I know? Those are all the errors that I'm getting. 404s since it's unable to access the resources. @WesleySmith

Comment: Ah, apologies, I didnt see the horizontal scroll

Comment: Can you please try removing this line `try_files $uri =404;` then running `sudo systemctl reload nginx`? Im not sure thats it by any means but Ive never seen that in any of the configs ive used or work with.

Comment: Also, lemme ask the obvious question, you are sure that these files actually exist at the path being accessed and that their permissions are set such that the user running nginx can read  them, right?

Comment: Take into account that with your config nginx would search any file requested as `http://localhost/forums/uploads/path/file` in `/var/www/forums/forums/uploads/path/` directory. Is this path correct?